# Apply color for 2 nth child paragraph tag but it apply for first paragraph tag

Tags: html, css

I apply the color red for the nth-child(2) for a paragraph tag but the color red apply for a first child . Any reason i am confused

```
<div>
    <h1>Fox story</h1>
    <p>the fox is lied between the lake</p>
    <p>that is the possible way </p>

</div>
```

style be

```
p:nth-child(2){

    color:red;
}
```

I tried on the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/E6n9E/)

Comment: That's because the `p` *is* the second child. You possibly want `p:nth-of-type(2)`

Answer (score 4):

Try  [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type)

```
p:nth-of-type(2){  
    color:red;
}
```

You are targeting second child and the second child is that first `<p>` tag. So here you have to specify the type element instead of child.

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/E6n9E/2/)

Answer (score 1):

`nth-child` counts all childs, so `H1` is first one, `first p` is the second one.

Use `nth-of-type` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can also use `:last-child` or `p + p` (if you're sure that number of paragraphs don't gonna change. Otherwise `nth-of-type(2)` :)